# WSO2IS Custom Properties on Tenants

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'd like to have custom properties that can be configured on a per-tenant basis to drive Custom Password Policies. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure password policies tenant wise. Follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Password+Policies) official documentation to configure

- Password History Validation
- Password Patterns

These configurations are available in the "Resident Identity Provider" level of each tenant.

But there is no any standard way to have custom properties per-tenant basis.

Comment: I did find that documentation. Basically I'm trying to implement https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Password+Policy+Authenticator (this is what I meant by Custom Password Policies above), where I can have each tenant specify the "
Authentication.Policy.Password.Reset.Time.In.Days" (I'm probably going to edit the code in that doc anyway). Is there a (non-standard) way to attach arbitrary properties to tenant?

Comment: If you want to use the same thing in the connector, I suggest you to use it, rather than going for a customization.

Comment: For anyone coming back here. We decided to store these properties in our own database, and added that to our datasources (so we could query it)